# Python 2.7 CSV Global Name 'r' not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Trying to write a simple row of data to a CSV file using method below.

```
 b = open ('team.csv','r')
 r.csv.writer(b)

 data = [Team_Name, Team_Suburb, Team_PH, Team_EF, Team_MD, Team_CSR, Team_PS]
 r.writerow(data)
 b.close()
```

Returning the following error message. **global name 'r' not defined**. Running Python 2.7.

Comment: Where do you define `r` ;) ?

Comment: `r.csv.writer(b)` should be `r = csv.writer(b)` , no? Also, aren't you opening the file in read mode?

Comment: You probably also want to put quotes around your column headings `['Team_Name', 'Team_Suburb', 'Team_PH', 'Team_EF', 'Team_MD', 'Team_CSR', 'Team_PS']` unless you have defined them before.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to write data to csv.
to write data, you should open write mode.

```
import csv
with open('checkout.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    data = [Team_Name, Team_Suburb, Team_PH, Team_EF, Team_MD, Team_CSR, Team_PS]
    writer.writerow(data)
```

you should set writer for csv file not r.
r is not declared..

Comment: in with open() you don't have to write close(). check this http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: Works fine but deletes previous row data

Comment: oh, my mistake.. your previous data means 'data in csv' isn' it? and then you can change 'wb' to 'a' in open(). w is clear, a means add

Comment: Its deleting it because you are opening it in `"wb"`; and that will truncate the file everytime you open it.

Comment: WorkLikeBear: I think the OP wants to append rows to an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('team.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    data = [Team_Name, Team_Suburb, etc, etc, etc]
    writer.writerow(data)
```